# Gettng Error WLClient onInvokeProcedureFailure:userInfo in WLClient.m

Tags: apple-watch, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-studio

We are getting below error while calling a simple HTTP Adaptor through iOS Apple Watch OS1. We have mobilefirst 6.3 with WorklightAPI iOS deployed on server.

```html
 [WL_CLIENT] -[WLClient onInvokeProcedureFailure:userInfo:] in WLClient.m

Status: 0
InvocationResult: (null)
InvocationContext: (null)
Error code: 3
Error message: Procedure invocation error.
```

It runs fine when we run it on development server. Only difference we see is on Test server TLSv1.2 is enabled while on development it is not.

We defined ATS --> Allow Arbitrary Loads = YES  in info.plist
but we are still getting an error.

Any Advice ?

Comment: I'll say it again. Apple Watch is not officially supported by MobileFirst at the time being...

Comment: Yes we know ... but errorcode 3 and message is coming from invokeprocedure method can someone advice when this comes ? Thanks

Comment: If your question is truly unrelated to Apple Watch then feel free to open a new question. Anytime you mention Apple Watch I won't be able to help because it's not supposed to work period.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned multiple times, Apple Watch is **not supported**. And in any case, since this is Watch OS 1 it means you invoke the code from the "parent" iOS app, no? In which case this was answered in your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34206002/there-is-no-registered-challenge-handler